HTML5 video player is not working on crome browser
<video id="autoplayVideo" controls autoplay muted playsinline>
    <source src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D0UnqGm_miA" type="application/x-mpegURL">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var video = document.getElementById('autoplayVideo');
    if (video.paused) {
        video.play();
    }
});
</script>



With this code video is properly playing on other browsers except Chrome.
Video should autoplay in crome browser
